# How does the built-in function "sorted" work in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, built-in

```
x = [1, 4, 7, 65, 23, 57, 12]
>>> sorted(x)
[1, 4, 7, 12, 23, 57, 65]
```

Just out of curiosity, how does this function work? What is the algorithm that Python uses to sort iterables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python  used to use [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Then, [the mighty Tim Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705542/tim-peters) came along, with a level 20 keyboard and coding chops that were over 9000; and in a magnificent symphony of elegance and brilliance, built [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) and gifted it to us mere mortals, for our lives would be incomplete without it.

Comment: Timsort *cough* :)

Comment: Yes, it's Timsort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Comment: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt

Comment: No, it's not just "... Tim Peters came along ... ". It should be "... the mighty Tim Peters came along ...". :-)

Comment: FWIW, No python implementation uses QuickSort these days for the simple reason that python's sort is (now) guaranteed to be stable.  I believe that I heard a while back that IronPython uses MergeSort, but I haven't verified that myself (and the information might be outdated).

Comment: @Matthias: how's that?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Yeah, that's a pythonic explanation.

Comment: Just noting that [the current version](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/listsort.txt) of `listsort.txt` adds some notes to address common confusions.